# Mistaken score in a quiz game written in c programming language

Tags: c

I was watching a C tutorial and I came up with a quiz game with the following code:

```
char questions[][100] = {"1. What year did the C language debut?: ", 
                         "2. Who is credited with creating C?: ",
                         "3. What is the predecessor of C?: "};

char options[][100] = {"A. 1969", "B. 1972", "C. 1975", "D. 1999",
                       "A. Dennis Ritchie", "B. Nicola Tesla", "C. C. John Carmack", "D. Doc Brown",
                       "A. Objective C", "B. B", "C. C++", "D. C#"};

char answers[3] = {'B', 'A', 'B'};
int numberOfQuestions = sizeof(questions)/sizeof(questions[0]);

char guess;
int score;

printf("QUIZ GAME\n");

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++)
{
    printf("***********************\n");
    printf("%s\n", questions[i]);
    printf("***********************\n");

    for(int j = (i * 4); j < (i * 4) + 4; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", options[j]);
    }

    printf("guess: ");
    scanf("%c", &guess);  
    scanf("%*c"); 

    guess = toupper(guess);

    if(guess == answers[i])
    {
        printf("CORRECT!\n");
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("WRONG!\n");
    }
}

printf("***********************\n");
printf("FINAL SCORE: %d/%d\n", score, numberOfQuestions);
printf("***********************\n");

return 0;
```

}

When running the code in bash script, I don't get my score in 2/3 or 3/3 but in values like:
1819435367/3 or 3483/3

Do you know what I am doing wrong in my program?

Comment: You need to initialize your variables (e.g. `int score = 0`). In c variables are usually **not** default initialized (to 0 or anything else).

Comment: Note that if you compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall`), then `score` not being initialized would have been flagged by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This, `int score;`, declares a variable, but doesn't *initialize* it to any particular value and thus its value will be *indeterminate*. Assuming this value is declared in a function, it will use *stack* memory and its value will be whatever bits where in this memory location previous, now interpreted as an `int`.
The solution is to initialize the variable: `int score = 0;`.

Alternatively, you could also declare the variable at *file scope* (often called global scope) and make it static. This guarantees (among other things) that integers will be initialized to 0. Example:

```c
static int score;

int main(void)
{
    print("%d\n", score);  // this will print '0'
}
```

To avoid these kind of errors, compile your program with all warning enabled (use the `-Wall` flag). To track these errors down, run your program with Valgrind.